# Extracting values by parsing JSON with Classic ASP

Tags: json, asp-classic

I am using Classic ASP and ASPJSON (http://www.aspjson.com/) to try to extract data returned in JSON format when sending an email via the SendGrid API.

This is some sample JSON data:

```
{  
   "message":"error",
   "errors":[  
      "some errors"
   ]
}
```

I can access the values of the "message" section via:

```
Set oJSON = New aspJSON
oJSON.loadJSON(string_containing_json)

json_status = ap(oJSON.data("message"))

response.write(json_status)
```

However, I can't access the values of the "errors" section as it's sort of one level down.

Is it possible to get at that?

Comment: Maybe you could try https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON. It is fast and integrates better with ASP than other libs. And it also have utility methods to load ADO recordsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are stored as a Dictionary object. You can enumerate them like this:

```
dim errors : set errors = oJSON.data("errors")
dim curError
for curError = 0 to errors.Count -1
  Response.Write( errors(curError))
  Response.Write( "<br />")
next
```

Comment: Thank you schudel!